# Add xml-stylesheet tag simpleXML php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Hy guys this is my simple code:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<p:FatturazioneElettronica xmlns:p="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://dummy.com"/>');

$xml->addAttribute("versione","FPR12");

$FatturaElettronicaHeader = $xml->addChild('FatturaElettronicaHeader',null,'http://dummy.com');
```

the xml results is:

```
<p:FatturazioneElettronica xmlns:p="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://dummy.com" versione="FPR12">

 <FatturaElettronicaHeader>
  <DatiTrasmissione>
   ....
```

How can add at the top of my xml "xml-stylesheet"?

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="fatturapa_v1.2.xsl" ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SimpleXML isn't very good at doing anything other than simple things (think that's were the name is very apt).  The only way I can think of doing it is to use DOMDocument, which provides a richer API and you should be able to do it as follows...

```
$xmlD = new DOMDocument( "1.0", "ISO-8859-15" );
$xmlD->appendChild($xmlD->createProcessingInstruction('xml-stylesheet', 'type="text/xsl" href="fatturapa_v1.2.xsl"'));
$xmlD->appendChild($xmlD->importNode(dom_import_simplexml($xml)));

echo $xmlD->saveXML();
```

This creates a new DOMDocument instance and then adds a few things.  First it uses `createProcessingInstruction()` to add the processing instruction for the style sheet.  Then it imports the existing contents of your SimpleXML document (in `$xml`) and appends this to the end.  The `echo` should give you a document something like...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="fatturapa_v1.2.xsl"?>
<p:FatturazioneElettronica xmlns:p="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://dummy.com" versione="FPR12"/>
```

Comment: it is a great suggestion, but if i add your code and print all it's empty.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *and print all it's empty*

Comment: If i print "echo $xmlD->saveXML();" with your code, on "video" it doesn't result

Comment: echoing out the XML will just display the XML in the browser - if you do 'view source' it should be there.